# TheA11yMachine not analyzing all the URLs

Tags: accessibility

I am trying to execute the [TheA11yMachine](https://github.com/liip/TheA11yMachine) for a publicly accessible site.
The tool identifies 128 URLs and fetches them but does not analyze them.

But somehow it stops after analysing more than 60 but less than 100 URLs.
There is no error also.

Where can I look for it?